# How to enable AD user's exchange and Lync accounts programmatically using LDAP in C#

Tags: c#, active-directory, exchange-server, lync, directoryentry

I am creating a new AD user on the domain server using the following code snippet:

```
DirectoryEntry newUser = directoryEntry.Children.Add("CN=" + model.Account.FullName, "user");
if (model.Account.SamAccountName != null) newUser.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value = model.Account.SamAccountName;
newUser.CommitChanges();

setUserPassword("CN=" + model.Account.FullName + "," + model.Account.Path, model.Account.Password);

newUser.RefreshCache();

if (model.Account.FirstName != null) newUser.Properties["givenName"].Add(model.Account.FirstName);
if (model.Account.LastName != null) newUser.Properties["sn"].Add(model.Account.LastName);
if (model.Account.MiddleName != null) newUser.Properties["initials"].Add(model.Account.MiddleName);

if (model.Account.UPNLogon != null && model.Account.DomainName != null) newUser.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Add(model.Account.UPNLogon + "@" + model.Account.DomainName);
if (model.Organization.DisplayName != null) newUser.Properties["displayName"].Add(model.Organization.DisplayName);
if (model.Organization.Email != null) newUser.Properties["mail"].Add(model.Organization.Email);

newUser.Properties["LockOutTime"].Value = 0; //unlock account
newUser.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = 0x200; // enable account
newUser.CommitChanges();

string homeMDB = profile.Exchange13_Profile.ExchangeDB;

IMailboxStore mailbox;
try
{
     IMailboxStore mailbox = (IMailboxStore)NewUser;
     mailbox.CreateMailbox(sHomeMDB);
     NewUser.CommitChanges();
}
catch (InvalidCastException e)
{
     MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString());
}
```

The above code successfully creates a new user and enables it on the AD server. But I am unable to create/enable the Exchange mailbox, as the `IMailboxStore` namespace needs `cdoexm.dll`. I've tried to locate `cdoexm.dll` on the Domain Controller, MailBox Server, and Client Access Server, but in vein.

I know the alternate way of doing this, is by using Powershell cmdlets, but I don't want to do that.

Now precisely stating my questions:

- How to add the COM `cdoexm.dll`? Or
- Is there any other way around to use `IMailBoxStore`? Or
- Is there any way to enable the AD user's mailbox and Lync account other than PowerShell?

The first two questions are resolved as CDOEXM is now obsolete from Exchange 2010 and onward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CDOEXM is removed starting from Exchange 2007.
And this is not an assembly, it's COM.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deva/archive/2010/01/13/update-technologies-not-available-with-exchange-2010-their-migration-reference-s.aspx

Did some searching, I can only find solution using PowerShell, 
or use c# to call PowerShell.

**To use C# to call PowerShell:**

Add "usings":

```
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Remoting;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
```

Calling the cmdlet:

```
PSCredential newCred = (PSCredential)null;
WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("http://exchangeserver01.my.domain/powershell?serializationLevel=Full"), 
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", newCred);
connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();

PSCommand command = new PSCommand();
command.AddCommand("Enable-Mailbox");
command.AddParameter("Identity", user.Guid.ToString());
command.AddParameter("Alias", user.UserName);
command.AddParameter("DomainController", ConnectingServer);
powershell.Commands = command;

try
{
    runspace.Open();
    powershell.Runspace = runspace;
    Collection<psobject> results = powershell.Invoke();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string er = ex.InnerException.ToString();
}
finally
{
    runspace.Dispose();
    runspace = null;

    powershell.Dispose();
    powershell = null;
}
```

The above is is copied from the following links (not tested):

http://codingchris.com/2012/02/15/creating-exchange-2010-mailboxes-in-c/
http://codingchris.com/2014/02/11/creating-exchange-2013-mailbox-in-c/

But as you want solution other than PowerShell, may be the above is not useful...

Comment: Thanks for the info on CDOEXM. Although powershell script do the trick but do let me know if anything else comes along

Answer (score 0):

To enable a mailbox for an existing AD user, use the [`enable-mailuser`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996549%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) powershell command.

To enable the Lync account, use the [`enable-csuser`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398711.aspx) powershell command.

Comment: Thanks Willem. I know the powershell alternate but i m finding a better way to do this.

Comment: I'm not aware of one, especially as far as Lync goes.